# sql create random table function

Tags: sql

So I am new to SQL and this is actually my very first project..
What I am trying to do is to create a fanction that returns a table with random numbers. I am using pgAdmin 4 IDE

This is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_amka(n integer)
RETURNS TABLE(amka integer) AS
$$
BEGIN
 return query

  select cast(random()*100 as integer)
  ORDER BY random() LIMIT n;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE;
```

So the fanction has an input (n integer) and is supposed to return a table with n random numbers. But it only returns 1 number. Is the "LIMIT n" the problem? Is there a better way to create such a fanction?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return `n` numbers, you an use `generate_series()`:

```
select cast(random()*100 as integer)
from generate_series(1, n);
```

There is no need to order them.  They are already random.

Comment: yep it worked.. didnt know this generate_series() function existed.. thx a lot man!